# Filling a memory segment with a bit pattern

Tags: assembly

I want to fill a memory segment with a certain byte pattern using powerpc assembly:

```
# Task: Fill the area from 0x8000 to (inclusive) 0x8FFF with 0x55 (per byte read/write)

# Write start address - 1 into a register
addis r2, r0, 0x0000
ori r2, r2, 0x7FFF

# Bit pattern is 0x55
addi r3, r0, 0x55

# Size of memory segment + 1
addis r4, r0, 0x0000 
ori r4, r4, 0x1000
# Move that length to CTR register
mtctr r4

loop:
#Write pattern from r3 into the address (1 + r2), and write the result of 1 + r2 back into r2
stbu r3, 1(r2)
# decrement CTR and see if we have reached the end of the segment
bdnz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some unnecessary comments. For example, this comment:

```
# Move that length to CTR register
mtctr r4
```

Anyone who knows this instruction set should be easily able to know what that line is doing.

Comments are supposed to explain **why**, not **how** because "how" is very easy to find out on one's own.

---

You did not specify what assembler you were using, but if your assembler allows for creating macros, I recommend that you make macros for those "random" numbers that are in your code.

These "random" numbers are called magic numbers; they've just appeared out of no-where.

In the NASM assembler, you can do something like this:

```
%define BIT_PATTERN 0x55
```

Then, in the line where you are working with the bit pattern, you write:

```
addi r3, r0, BIT_PATTERN
```

And now there is no confusion about where that number came from and you can remove that comment from above this line.

You should see if you can create macros for this bit pattern like I showed you, and for the memory segment addresses.

---

*Note: I could not find a PowerPC assembler any where on the internet so my recommendations from here on may be slightly flawed in some places.*

These lines can be simplified:

```
addis r2, r0, 0x0000
ori r2, r2, 0x7FFF
```

All you seem to be trying to do here is stick the value `0x7FFF` into the register `r2`. However, you are taking two instructions to do this:

1. Move 0 into `r2`
2. Make `r2` become `0x7FFF` with `ori`

This seems a little unnecessary; why can't you just put `0x7FFF` into `r2` to begin with, like you did when you put the bit pattern into `r3`? A much simpler way of writing this would be:

```
li r2, 0x7FFF
```

which is directly equivalent to

```
addi r2, 0, 0x7FFF
```

*Note: This assumes that r0 was 0 to being with, which I think it was.*

The above will put the value `0x7FFF` into `r2`. You can do this same thing for when you are putting the size of the memory segment into `r4`, and when you are putting the bit pattern into `r3`.

It didn't look like you specifically needed to actually use the `addis` instruction, which seems unnecessarily complicated for simply putting a value into a register.

However, if you did, just change the instruction to:

```
lis r2, 0x7FFF
```

---

You are using the registers incorrectly.

According to [this page](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~mburrel/stuff/ppc-asm.html), the registers `r2`, `r3`, and `r4` are for the table of contents pointer, the return of a function/subroutine, and (commonly) a function/subroutine argument, respectively.

I think you should be using the register `r4` through `r10` because, since you are not using a subroutine, these registers can now be used for general purpose. You *might* be okay with using `r3`, but you definitely should not be using `r2`.

---

Putting it all together:

```
li r4, 0x7FFF
li r5, 0x55
li r6, 0x1000

mtctr r6

loop:
    stbu r5, 1(r4)
    bdnz
```

---

*If you notice any bugs, notify me.*

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!
About  "Note: This assumes that r0 was 0 to being with, which I think it was.": r0 means in certain commands the literal 0, see here: http://pds.twi.tudelft.nl/vakken/in101/labcourse/instruction-set/addi.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't know PPC at all, so this is all general.

The first thing that jumps out is that you're using single-byte writes. On most architectures, it is much more efficient to write a full register at a time (i.e. a 32-bit `0x55555555`). Since this only uses 1/4th as many writes, it should be about 4x as fast. If you have wider SIMD registers, they might increase performance even more. Of course, you should measure.

If you can't guarantee that your start and end will be word-aligned, write the leading and trailing partial word separately.

You might also benefit from unrolling the loop so that you do multiple writes before the branch.